# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at Solution.recur(File.java:58)

Tags: recursion

class Solution{
ArrayList subsetSums(ArrayList arr, int N){

```
    int sum=0;
    
    ArrayList<Integer> temparr = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1;i<=arr.size();i++)
    {
       for(int j = 0; i < arr.size()-i+1 ; j++)
         temparr.add(recur(arr,i,j,sum));   
    }
    
    return temparr;
}


int recur(ArrayList<Integer> arr,int i,int j,int sum)
{
    int index = j;
    int len = i;
    int Sum = sum;
    if(len==0)
    {
        return Sum;
    } 
    Sum += arr.get(index);
    return recur(arr,len--,index++,Sum);
 }
```

}

,,,
I'm getting stack overflow error in  'return recur(arr,len--,index++,Sum);'
'''

Comment: I haven't tested it, just a side note: perhaps `i < arr.size()-i+1` should have been `j < arr.size()-i+1`

Comment: Another finding: try passing `len - 1` and `index + 1` instead of the short notation. The reason is that the value of the expression `len--` is the original value of `len`; the variable (which only exists locally but not used anymore after this line) is decremented afterwards.

Comment: If you insist on using those operators, you can use the variant which is written before the variable: `--len` and `++index` (they first increment/decrement the variable and then return the updated value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the main problem here (see comments for potential other problems) is the way you are trying to pass changed arguments to the recursive invocation:

```
recur(arr,len--,index++,Sum)
```

Actually this will call `recur` with the unchanged values of `len` and `index` because the operators `++` and `--` (when written on the right side of a variable) are defined to return the original value of the variable and *then* update the variable's value.

Use (I would prefer this)

```
recur(arr, len-1, index+1, Sum)
```

or (okay, but the assignment is not needed)

```
recur(arr, --len, ++index, Sum)
```

to actually pass the modified value to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a recursion limit. The way to fix this is replace the recursion with a loop. (Or change the function so it does not recur as much. Infinite loops are a problem just as infinite recursion is).

A few tips for the future:

- Google the documentation for errors
- State the language with a tag in posts
- Don't use formatting of line 1
- Debug with print statements